# How to display a button with an image only in the desired tab?

Tags: java, processing, control-p5

I have *OKNO1* and *OKNO2*, I want to show a button with an image strictly in OKNO1.

At the moment, the button with the image is shown globally.
I used to use `cp5.addButton` and there I did it with `.moveTo("okno1");`

Now the image button uses OOP/Java.
How to solve a tricky problem? What ways can you do the task. I think to use again `void draw()`.

[image][image]

Complete code example:

```
import controlP5.*;
ControlP5 cp5;
ImageButton button;
Textlabel I;
Textlabel tempIn;

void setup() {
  size(700, 420, P3D);
  surface.setResizable(false);
  smooth();
  frameRate(30);
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

  PFont p = createFont("Times New Roman", 18);
  ControlFont font=new
    ControlFont(p);
  cp5.setFont(font);

  cp5.addTab("okno2")
    .setColorBackground(color(0, 160, 100))
    .setColorLabel(color(255))
    .setColorActive(color(255, 128, 0));

  cp5.getTab("default")
    .activateEvent(true)
    .setLabel("okno1")
    .setId(1);

  cp5.getTab("okno2")
    .activateEvent(true)
    .setId(2);

  tempIn = cp5.addTextlabel("Sostoyanie")
    .setText("1")
    .setFont(createFont("Times New Roman", 20))
    .setColor(color(0xffffff00))
    .setPosition(155, 35);

  I = cp5.addTextlabel("Impuls")
    .setText("2")
    .setPosition(155, 35)
    .setFont(createFont("Times New Roman", 20))
    .setColor(color(0xffffff00))
    .moveTo("okno2");

  int w = 99;
  int h = 25;
  button = new ImageButton(112, 137, w, h, 
    new PImage[]{
    loadImage("0.png"), // off
    loadImage("1.png"), // 10
    loadImage("2.png"), // 20
    loadImage("3.png"), // 30
    loadImage("4.png"), // 40
    loadImage("5.png"), // 50
    loadImage("6.png"), // 60
    });
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  button.draw();
}
void mousePressed() {
  button.mousePressed(mouseX, mouseY);
  println(button.min);
}
PImage getImage(int w, int h, int c) {
  PImage img = createImage(w, h, RGB);
  java.util.Arrays.fill(img.pixels, c);
  img.updatePixels();
  return img;
}
class ImageButton {
  int min = 0;
  PImage[] stateImages;
  int stateIndex;
  int x, y;
  int w, h;
  String label = "ВЫКЛ";
  ImageButton(int x, int y, int w, int h, PImage[] stateImages) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.stateImages = stateImages;
  }
  void mousePressed(int mx, int my) {
    boolean isOver = ((mx >= x && mx <= x + w) &&
      (my >= y && my <= y + h) ); // check vertical
    if (isOver) {
      min += 10;
      stateIndex++;
      if (min>60) {
        min = 0; 
        stateIndex = 0;
        label = "ВЫКЛ";
      } else {
        label = min + " Мин";
      }
    }
  }
  void draw() {
    if (stateImages != null && stateIndex < stateImages.length) {
      image(stateImages[stateIndex], x, y, w, h);
    } else {
      println("error displaying button state image");
      println("stateImages: ");
      printArray(stateImages);
      println("stateIndex: " + stateIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Help others (including myself) help you:

- keep the code tidy (remove anything that is unnecessary, like the `getImage` for example)
- format the code so it's easy to read. I can't stress this enough.

To help yourself always make sure you understand all your code completely:

- read it
- imagine in your head how it would run
- run it and observe the actual behaviour
- understand what was different between your mental model and what the computer did.

This will help you debug code in general. Also checkout [Kevin Workman's Debugging tutorial](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging).

Regarding your issue: the button is rendered all the time in `draw()`.
You want to only draw it when the first tab is active hence:

- get the first tab
- check if it's active
- if so, render the button

e.g instead of `button.draw()` you'd use:

```
if(cp5.getTab("default").isActive()){
    button.draw();
  }
```

That will do the trick, but as you interface gets more complex, you may want group what's being drawn per tab. Here's an idea on how to organise for a UI with more controls per tab:

- add a global variable (at the top of your code) to keep track of the current tab: `int currentTab = 1;`
- call `displayTabs();` in `draw()` instead of `button.draw()` to handle per tab drawing. (More about `displayTabs()` bellow)
- `controlEvent()` to update the `currentTab`

Like so:

```
void controlEvent(ControlEvent event) {
  // update current tab only if the current event comes from a tab (and not other controllers) 
  if(event.isTab()){
    currentTab = event.getId();
  }
}
```

The idea is `controlEvent` will get triggered when any ControlP5 component (controller) is clicked/updated. If it's a tab you can update `currentTab` to know in `draw()` which content to `draw()` using `displayTabs()`:

```
void displayTabs(){
  switch(currentTab){
    case 1:
      displayTab1();
      break;
    case 2:
      displayTab2();
      break;
  }
}

void displayTab1(){
  button.draw();
}

void displayTab2(){
  // render stuff for tab 2 only
}
```

So there's one switch with calls one function or another depending on the `currentTab` value. The advantage of doing things this was is that you can easily replicate another  `case` for another tab in the future and each tab content is neatly compartmentalised.

Comment: As always, you are a master of problem solving. I will try to take into account your requirements with the code.

Comment: Of course, I understand that we just determined where to show the button. It is still there, it is simply not visible in the second window. This means that you can set isActive = false there, or put a block on clicking in the second window near the button. Visually it is not, but the physical is.

Comment: Indeed, the above would simply take care of not rendering the button, but the interaction logic is still there (meaning the mouse press will affect the invisible button). You should apply the same logic that only renders the button on the correct tab in `mousePressed()` so the button is only updated if the right tab is active. You might want to look at the `switch` statement as a crude [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine): ideally you would write a state machine machine using classes to handle states (each handling mouse/keyboard/rendering independently)

Comment: I haven't had the time to answer anyone in almost a month now. I'm afraid I won't have the time to answer your question. Double check the [`switch`](https://processing.org/reference/switch.html) reference/examples and try to isolate the problem (copy only the bare minimum to reproduce the issue in a new sketch, debug/fix there, then implement the fox in the big sketch.